# How to use "truncatechars" in flask? ( Error : No filter named 'truncatechars'. )

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to use **truncatechars** in flask. When previously I used **truncatechars**  in django the following code worked

The code (Django):

```html
<div class="preview">{{post.content |safe| truncatechars:500}}</div>
```

But when I use truncatechars in flask it throws an error saying **jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: No filter named 'truncatechars_html'.**

The code (Flask):

```html
<div class="preview">{{post.content |safe| truncatechars(500)}}</div>
```

When I used "**:**" instead of brackets "**()**" it throwed an error saying **jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got ':'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jinja2 this filter is called [`truncate`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.truncate):

```
<div class="preview">{{ post.content|safe|truncate(500) }}</div>
```

Comment: problem is that truncate will break HTML tags in that string ...